# Rackspace Cloud Server / DB - getaddrinfo failed

Tags: mysql, php, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

I recently migrated my MySQL instance from my debian server to a cloud database server at rackspace.  A couple times of day since then, I notice in the log files that we have the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I can only see maybe 200 or 300 open connections total on the server at a given time, so I don't know that I would be running into connection limits.

Has anyone else had this issue with cloud databases?  My only thought currently is that there is either some sort of DNS resolution issue happening, or some how the server is unable to handle the extra tcp traffic.  Any ideas on what to look at next?

Comment: Hopefully, it means you've got a piece of code somewhere with a typo in a server hostname.  Otherwise, as you may suspect, it is a problem with DNS or the resolver... but this should not actually be anything to do with MySQL itself.

Comment: This happens at random across various sites and applications, so it's not a typo.  I'm working through how to debug this further currently.